# Which version of GCC introduced support for atomic builtins?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, atomic

I see it's available in 4.1.0 but was it available earlier than this? I'm interested specifically in 3.4.3 but can't find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), it seems the atomic builtins were added in the 4.1 release.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the GCC manual for 3.4.6 here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/

It makes no mention of the Atomic Builtins, so I'd guess that they aren't in 3.4.3.

A list of historical GCC manuals is here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/

And a list of links to release notes: http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

Answer (score 1):

You could check the changelog, e.g. `cat /usr/share/doc/gcc-YOUR-VERSION-OF-GCC/ChangeLog | grep atomic`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an earlier version, you should still be able to use them with inline assembler.

Comment: Thanks. Right now I'm mandating baseline 4.1.2 support but will look into this should I require to support earlier releases.